# If a file is updated on a server, will the header expire on visitors' browser?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching

This is without a doubt a dumb question but I can't seem to find an answer to it.

I just added mod_deflate and header expire in my htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|js|css)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>
```

My question was, if I update a CSS sheet, will my visitors' browser figure out that it's been modified or will it completely ignore it and won't grab it again until it expires (a week after) ?

Thanks

Comment: max-age is just a hint to the browser for MAXIMUM time that it should cache the data for. It's up to the browser to determine what the MINIMUM time is, but it's been told that after 604800 seconds, it SHOULD request a fresh copy.

Comment: @MarcB so in theory if it checks the a css sheet, it will know it has been modified and will not use the cached version, correct?

Comment: depends on the browser. generally a browser will include an `If-Modified-Since` header to tell the server when the browser last fetched a copy, and the server may choose to respond with a `304 not modified`, telling the browser to just use the cached copy. still does a full http round-trip, but since 304 doesn't include a body, there's just some http headers transferred.

Comment: @MarcB
So how I make sure that my visitors are going to have an updated stylesheet?

Comment: Set a short 'expires' on the file. You don't want the users hitting your server for EVERY request to get an updated copy, but also don't want them using a stale copy too long. you'll have to figure out an appropriate balance.